# PDO PHP , LOGIN FORM

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, pdo

any help would be appreciated. I have a login form, I can't figure out how to check for password when user enters it in, It only checks for username and validates. Its only a simple login, not much emphasis on security.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

```
public function adminl() {
    if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['passw'])) {
        // get user's data
        $con = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, 
            username, passw,
            passw   
            FROM admin
            WHERE username = :username;");

        $con->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['passw']));
        $count =  $con->rowCount();

        if ($count == 1) { 
            if( $con->execute(array(':passw' => $_POST['username'])) == 1) {
                // fetch one row 
                $result = $con->fetch;
                return true;
                echo "success"; 
            } 
        }  
        else {
            echo "Failed to login";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **warning** don't store passwords in a database use a salt+hash system.

Comment: warning! Not all applications are in the wild (i.e. intranet only) and don't need salts and hashes. Stop assuming you know what the OP is using something for and just answer questions. Let them worry about the security.

Comment: Why are you executing the query again? You've alread retrieved the password (if the account exists) in the first query, so there's **NO** point in re-executing the query again. Just fetch the row and compare password values. And as Daniel pointed out above, you do **NOT** **EVER** store passwords as plaintext in your database.

Comment: `array(':username' => $_POST['passw'])` and `array(':passw' => $_POST['username'])`?

Comment: @mjayt - salting and hashing with a library is generally so trivial, one may as well do it everywhere. But, it's an interesting point.

Comment: @mjayt - Our payroll system is intranet only, and I would be quite disappointed if it was insecure and caused me to lose my paycheck. To me, security should be a concern of any good developer, regardless of the execution environment.

Comment: @mjayt That is never an excuse. Even though it may not be a problem that a system is not well secured because it's not connected to the internet, does not mean everyone's password should be stored for every sysadmin to see.

Comment: @joost, I wholeheartedly disagree. I don't need to write password reset/management code for data that isn't secure. You might work in a fluffy environment where you can waste time, but I don't. To suggest a payroll system as nickb did is ignorant at best. That was not my implication and I'm sad if anyone feels it was. The point was, not everything is secure, sometimes it is just "protected". The overhead is unnecessary. Period.

Comment: and it is a concern... when it needs to be. I prefer a developer that is comfortable knowing the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have `username = :username` in your query, whereas, when executing the prepared query, you are passing the `array(':username' => $_POST['passw'])` to it. I don't think that is the intended behaviour here.
2. At a later stage, you are executing the same statement by passing `array(':passw' => $_POST['username'])` to its execute call; whereas, there is no placeholder named `passw` in your query.
3. You are not calling the function `fetch()` but instead, trying to access a variable named `fetch` in the object `$con`.

---

#### NOTE

As already [commented by Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964705/pdo-php-login-form#comment28009819_18964705), please don't store passwords in a database as plaintext. Use a salt + hash system.

---

Perhaps, this is what you want to achieve:

```
$con = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id, 
        username,
        passw   
    FROM admin
    WHERE username = :username
        AND passw = :passw
    LIMIT 1");
$con->execute( array(':username' => $_POST['username'], ':passw' => $_POST['passw']) );
$count = $con->rowCount();
if( $count > 0 ) {
    $result = $con->fetch();
    return TRUE; // or $result, whatever is the intended behaviour
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works...But adding hashes would further complicate verification process. I use MySQL. Could you please give me a code based on what I already have and what modifcations to make on my passw and usernames fields on my database...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TeachaKyng You can simply search [so] for [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+or+%5Bmysql%5D+hashing+password+and+storing+in+db+is%3Aq) on storing hashed passwords or google around. There are several resources for the same.